# Multiple choice quiz with difficulty and topic options

Tags: python, python-3.x, quiz

This is my code for an MCQ with difficulty and question options. It uses a `namedtuple` for the questions, and puts them in an array, and uses a difficulty parameter to decide how many options are displayed. This is so that I can have 3 difficulty options: one which outputs 2, one 3, and one outputting 4.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Question = namedtuple("Question", "question answer choices correct")


maths_questions = [Question("What is 1 + 1", "1 + 1 is 2", ["1", "2", "3", "4"], {"b", "2"}),
                   Question("What is 2 + 3", "2 + 3 is 5", ["5", "4", "2", "1"], {"a", "5"})]

music_questions = [Question("Who sung Gangsta's paradise?", "Coolio", ["1", "2", "Coolio", "4"], {"c", "coolio", "3"}),
                   Question("What is DANK", "Weed is DANK", ["5", "4", "DANK", "1"], {"c", "dank", "3"})]
ansdict = []


def quiz(questions, difficulty):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        global ansdict; ansdict = question.choices
        print(question.question)  # PRINTS OUT QUESTION
        output(difficulty, ansdict)
        users_answer = input().lower()
        if users_answer in question.correct:  # checks whether users input is in the answer tuple
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect", question.answer)  # if incorrect outputs correct answer
    print("{} out of {}".format(score, len(questions)))


def output(difficulty, dicti):
    for i in range(difficulty):
        print(dicti[i])

quiz(music_questions, 4)
```

Comment: This is a good quiz, but when executed, an error message is outputted stating that 'list' object has no attribute 'correct'.